# Virsh Console Can't Access to rhel VM (a pty console, instead of serial console)

Tags: kvm-virtualization, libvirt, rhel6, qemu

1. the pty console:

```xml
<console type='pty'>
    <target type='virtio' />
    <alias name='console1'/>
</console>
```

2. **no output** when I exec the command `virsh ttyconsole vm_name`
3. the log (/var/log/libvirt/qemu/vm_name.log) :

```
char device redirected to /dev/pts/2 (label charconsole1)
```

4. when l exec `virsh console vm_name console1` , the command is stuck.
   Only output:

```
Connected to domain vm_name
Escape character is ^] (Ctrl + ]) (i had pressed enter button)
```

5. I had tried some methods([RHEL6 virsh console domain](http://blog.domb.net/?p=56)),like **editing /boot/grub/menu.lst and /etc/inittab**. But it can't solve the problem.